# What is the purpose of the downvoting questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

I am a new programmer and was recommended to the site by several teachers and my internship boss. They all said how great of a learning tool this was. But users keep downvoting my questions saying they are too easy and other things along that line.

Getting downvoted and those comments are very discouraging for a young coder like me, so what is the point of them? Do you not want the community to grow?

Comment: Quality control and feedback. Note the tooltip on the downvote button when you mouse-over: *This question does not show any research effort;  it is unclear or not useful*.

Comment: Are you sure people said they're "too easy" rather than that you hadn't done enough research, or put enough effort into asking the question *well*?

Comment: The bottom line is: don't take downvotes personally. Instead, try to improve your question-asking skills. Ask yourself how you'd react if someone came to you with a question about something they could easily have looked up in the textbook you are using for class. If they can tell you they already looked at that text and can explain why it wasn't helping them, you'd feel a lot more inclined to help them than when they gave the impression they couldn't be bothered to look in the textbook first.

Comment: Did you include what you tried in the questions? Here questions can be asked only after one attempts to code and faces a problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you only have a single downvote, and a single upvote. Where the downvotes you received for questions that have now been deleted, and if so, where those questions deleted by the community (should only happen to extremely bad questions), or where they deleted by yourself?

Comment: There is a fiction that SO is creating an archive of useful information, and, if that is the case, repeatedly asking the same naive questions does not advance that goal.  More realistically, questions that do not show any real effort on the part of the asker merit downvoting.

Comment: @HotLicks That's a ficiton? Have you ever tried a google search for a programming question? It's SO all the way down.

Comment: @Lattyware - Yes, but it's not an "archive" in any real sense -- more like a junkyard.

Comment: @HotLicks I disagree - there is a lot of high quality content, and it's got enough metadata to be pretty well structured. It's an archive in every relevant sense.

Comment: Try Google before asking on SO. Lots of beginners questions can be answered by correct Google search. Use SO when you are stuck, and have no more ideas how to solve the issue.

Comment: @Lattyware - It only works because Google works, and between the pollution of SO and Google dumbing down, it's working less well all the time.

Comment: Being able to code is one skill. Being able to communicate your problems clearly is another. You may be strong in the first, but you need some improvement on the latter. But don't give up. [Have a look at some of the most upvoted questions in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes). See what they have in common, in clarity of purpose and the way to communicate the problem or doubt. Then apply what you see to your own questions ;) also google for "rubber duck problem solving".

Comment: SO is a learning tool, yes. Nobody said that using only the "Ask Question" button is the tool. The tool is the search function first and foremost.

Comment: Well this is quite ironic.

Answer (score 21):

We don't downvote people.

We downvote posts. Posts that are not clear. Posts that are off-topic. Posts that are not asking a question. Posts that are low quality.

I can go on.

The converse is also true - good, high quality, clear posts get upvotes.

Votes are not a reflection on the person - but on the post.

---

Why do we do it?

Because it tells the person posting and the many many other people who might be reading it that it has problems.

It lets us clean up the bad content and keep the good content.

Answer (score 5):

The most probable reasons for the downvotes are:

1. You have just asked a question without doing any research on what you are asking.
2. Your question *proves* that you have no idea (lack minimal understanding) about what you are asking (happens loads of times with *how can I do this* kind of questions).
3. Your questions contain *incomplete information* or *are primarily opinion based* or *are too broad*.

Note: You usually get answers even for duplicated questions. For example - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) has been asked and answered (also, marked as *duplicate*) several hundred times.

So, we don't close questions and downvote blindly... We encourage people to ask more questions. But flawed ones should and will be removed to maintain quality on the site.